# Showing transitivity of a modulus

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Relation $V$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by setting $xVy$ iff $|x^2-y^2|\le2$. How do I show that this is transitive?

Comment: Transitivity needs to be proven in very few cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)(x-y) $ and since both $x $ and $y $ are integers, so are $x+y $ and $x-y $. Now $xVy$ iff one of three things happen:

$(x-y) = 0$ or $(x+y) = 0$ or ($|x| \le 2$ AND $|y| \le 2$).

$(x-y) = 0 \iff x=y \rightarrow |(x^2 - y^2)| = 0 \le 2$;

Note that we get the same when $x = -y $;

(Note that both these cases imply $x^2 = y^2$)

Now how can we get $|(x+y)(x-y)| \le 2$ when $x \ne \pm y$?

$$|(x+y)(x-y)| \le 2 \iff |(x+y)||(x-y)| \le 2 \iff |(x+y)| \le \frac{2}{|(x-y)|}$$

If $|(x-y)| > 2 $ this is rendered impossible because the only integer less than 1 (in modulo) is 0, and we already excluded that possibility. So $|(x-y)| \le 2$. If we divide both sides by $|(x+y)|$ instead, we get the analogue result: $|(x+y)| \le 2$. Both conditions are only met when $x$ is at a distance of 2 or less of both $y$ and $-y$.

How far apart can $y$ and $-y$ be on the integer line so that my statement is true? If you take a pen and a piece of paper you quickly realise that $|y|$ must be $\le 2$ and that the same thing goes for $x$.

Now transitivity can be proven easily:

We assume that $xVy $ and that $yVz $. To prove $xVz $ just consider the three cases above (that are just essentially two) for $x $ and $y $.

First assume $x = \pm y$ and then assume that both $|x|$ and $|y|$ are $\le2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(a+1)^2-a^2=2a+1$. The difference between two consecutive squares is 1 only when it is $0$ and $1$. Otherwise it is at least 3. If the squares are not of consecutive numbers then the difference will be much higher.

So the condition $|x^2-y^2|\leq 2$ actually means $x=0,y\pm1$; (or the other way), the set has just these 3 elements. So any checking has to be with these 3 numbers which holds; so transitivity follows.